# How to prevent activated mousedown event by function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, fabricjs

```
function itext(){
function addText() {
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(options) {
var left1=Math.round(options.e.clientX)-139;
var top1=Math.round(options.e.clientY)-250;
var newText = new fabric.IText("",{
    left:left1,
    top:top1
});
canvas.add(newText);
canvas.setActiveObject(newText);
newText.enterEditing();
newText.selectAll();
});
}
canvas.on('mouse:down', addText);
}
```

I want add some itext to canvas when i click on canvas.i do that using this function.after execute this function that mouseevent should be disabled.but i have no idea how to prevent activated mouseevent.any idea/example would be appreciated.thank you.

Comment: Set a boolean variable to false before the function is executed. Then your function checks to see if it is true, if it is true then it does nothing. If it is false, then it does what you want and sets the variable to true. This way it is only executed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a boolean variable to false before the function is executed. Then your function checks to see if it is true, if it is true then it does nothing. If it is false, then it does what you want and sets the variable to true. This way it is only executed once.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `e.PreventDefault` should work it will prevent the default click action form going through so your function should only trigger once per click